# Troble to install Qgis in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, installation

I format my notebook because this problem, but it wasn't solved. Any suggestion to fix it?

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-qgis : Depends: python-qgis-common (= 1:2.14.4-1+20trusty-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgispython2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgis-analysis2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgis-core2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgis-gui2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgis-networkanalysis2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqgis-server2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
 qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-1-0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not installable
        Depends: libgeos-c1v5 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis-analysis2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-app2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-core2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-gui2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-networkanalysis2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:2.14.4-1+20trusty-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-globe but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-provider-grass but it is not going to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:2.14.4-1+20trusty-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libqgis-app2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-core2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-gui2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgisgrass7-2.14.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show how you produced these error messages, please?

Comment: I changed my repository to http://qgis.org/debian-ltr and all worked well.